# How can I send a command to a CMD window in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have a program which runs in a CMD windows which accepts inputs.

**For example**:
The the CMD window is open, if I press R it turns the CMD to Red and if I press B it turns it back to Black.

**Question:**:
From a button in VB.Net how can I send the letter R to the open CMD window

Thanks

Comment: What kind of UI platform that Button belongs to? WinForms, WPF, other? Is the GUI app that's running the Console app or is it already running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from a bit of googling and my own experience I think maybe able to send commands to an existing CMD window at least by using VB.net I did found some solutions online I personally didn't test them my self but I'm sure you can ;) You can probably send commands through the ProcessStartInfo class' redirectstandardinput method [Try This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_RedirectStandardInput) Try this post also it seems to reslove your issue [Try this also](https://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/launching-and-controlling-external-applications-from-vb-net-application/), you can use `Process.start("CMD /k color fc")` Note: /k runs CMD and stays on , /c runs CMD and closes after excuting code

```
Colour codes available:
Code (Hex)  Color
0   black
1   blue
2   green
3   cyan
4   red
5   magenta
6   yellow/brown
7   white
8   gray
9   bright blue
A   bright green
B   bright cyan
C   bright red
D   bright magenta
E   bright yellow
F   white
```

Comment: Thank You. This has put me on the right path to try and get this working how I want it to.